# How can i use AMP pages in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, amp-html

I have setting up an AMP page in reactjs but AMP validator is showing this error:

> `Custom JavaScript is not allowed`

However, I have not used any custom-js in my page. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: which framework you are using for your application is it nextjs? or simple react-app

Comment: i have use reactjs framework.

Comment: How are you loading the React app *without* using custom JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading any external js or allowing any js injection. you can use [amp-iframe](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-iframe/?referrer=ampproject.org).Other option (in case no js injection) check for enabling javaScript redirection to SSL.

Comment: Can you please help me with the steps to solve?
Or can you please provide me the link relevant this issue.